# How can I group rows based on those that have the same value in a column, and then run my code on each subset?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, group-by, grouping

I have a csv file which I created through some lines of code that includes the following:

A 'BatchID' column, in the format of DEFGH12-01, specifying which batch each unit is in, and a column of the units and their full ID numbers, 'UnitID', in the format of DEFGH12-01_x01_y01. Each unit (UnitID) falls under a specific batch (and thus the Unit ID number corresponds to the BatchID it is under.

I have a certain algorithm that I have been running on the entire dataset of unit IDs. I want to group the units based on having the same batchID value (as there are many unique units that fall under each batch), and then running the algorithm on each of these subsets of unit batches.

How can I do this?

Comment: You might want to share your codes so far and a sample of your csv content, else we will be clueless to your question

Comment: Also you should show how your data frame appears after importing from your CSV file

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use pandas groupping.
here is an example:

creating data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3,4,5], "B":[1,2,3,4,5], "C": ['GROUP_A', 'GROUP_A', 'GROUP_A', 'GROUP_B', 'GROUP_B']})
```

applying your funcion:

```
groups_list = []
for group_name, group_values in df.groupby("C"):
    # applying a function on a column based on group
    group_values = group_values.assign(A=group_values.A.apply(lambda x: x ** 2))

    # for re-creating the df
    groups_list.append(group_values)

# if there is only 1 group , else is needed
mod_df = pd.concat(groups_list, axis=0) if len(groups_list) > 1 else groups_list[0]
print(mod_df)
```

Comment: But this doesn't tell me anything about the grouping of the unique batches

Comment: every group is a uniqe batch, and then apply your functions on the rest of the data. you can print the group name (or batch) using the group name inside the loop @azura

Comment: what I mean is that there are hundreds of batch IDs that are identical and correspond to unique unit IDs. I want to group each group of unit IDs to their batch ID

Comment: you need to give sample data because you are getting confusing, but think at pandas like an sql table - you can give a statement about a group without working on that froup, you can group by 2 columns - is this will help you, but ive lost track of your needs, also, when you open a question in Stack Overflow, try to include sample code and input data, as other people have already mentioned